# Automatic data recovery on the page without refresh in Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, laravel

I have a website in laravel and on it I would need, for example, every 5 seconds to load the data that is reloaded from the database on that page, but without the page reloading (without F5 for example) only some reload.  If it was not possible to load data on the whole page, then at least in the table and in the div.  Thank you all for your help, perhaps I have explained everything well and if not then I can try again.

Comment: read about ajax jquery

Comment: To load data from database without reload the page you can use Ajax. This link can help you to understand it [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Comment: Axios.js is a great, modern Ajax lib that doesn't require jQuery. It uses Promises, you can `await` requests, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataTable then,

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $("#table_id").DataTable({
                  ajax: "data-url"
                });

    setInterval( function () {
       table.ajax.reload();
    }, 5000 );
  )};
</script>
```

For more details go through below link,
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()